# How does on-premises cloud work?

Tags: virtual, cloud

Perhaps I don't understand exactly what the cloud is, but I am of the understanding that it is a model whereby computing resources (i.e. servers, computers, processors) are accessed over the Internet from a third party host's data center. I have recently come across the term 'on-premises cloud', and I am not exactly sure where this fits into the scheme of cloud services. I used to think the cloud is defined by the model whereby the computing resources are NOT owned/hosted locally by the firm, but there seems to be an application of the cloud whereby the 'cloud infrastructure' is located in the firm's internal data centers.

So if geography is not the primary factor in determining what can be considered as a cloud and what cannot, then what is? Is it:

Some form of 'cloud software' like Azure or Oracle Cloud@Customer that defines a cloud environment? In which case what does this software do?

The fact that it is being accessed over the Internet and not direct enterprise networks

The fact that the on-prem cloud servers are virtualized, whereas regular cloud servers would not be virtualized?

I know I'm coming from a very non-technical and junior perspective, so I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the academic answer, [NIST has published a nice paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-145.pdf) on what Cloud Computing is. The definition they use is:

> The NIST Definition of Cloud ComputingCloud computing is a model for
> enabling ubiquitous, convenient, on-demand network access to a shared
> pool of configurable computing resources (e.g., networks, servers,
> storage, applications, and services) that can be rapidly provisioned
> and released with minimal management effort or service provider
> interaction.

They also define five essential characteristics that any cloud computing solution has:

1. On-demand self-service
2. Broad network access
3. Resource pooling
4. Rapid elasticity
5. Measured service

Note that none of this mentions the internet, and you certainly can achieve all this for your company or customers with equipment running in your own datacenters. But the easiest way to consume all this is to just buy it from one of the big cloud providers.

Comment: Side note: while it is common to connect to 'the cloud' over the internet, there certainly are architectures where you would extend your corporate network to Azure/AWS/GCP/etc with private connections and avoid traffic to/from the cloud going over the interenet at all.

Comment: Thanks for this, but if we look at the definition provided by NIST, we can see that they define any cloud offering as something which should offer resource pooling i.e. the service provider's computing, storage, networking, etc. resources should be pooled to be made available to a host of users. Isn't this against on-prem cloud, which involves creating a dedicated cloud separate from the provider's infrastructure for the firm?

Comment: Regarding resource pooling, a organisation can elect to form its on-prem cloud and sell cloud resources to its own entities. A common method of payment is via transfer pricing.